# Name/style/model for this brake spring?

Tags: brakes

I bought a cheap assemble-yourself bike and the front brake spring came bent. I'm having trouble googling a replacement since its a no-name brand. Any advice on how I might go about buying a replacement?

[image]

[image]

(And obligatory safety disclosure: yes, I carefully inspected and tested the rest of the brake system to make sure this was the only defective part.)

Comment: You could twist it back into line with two pairs of pliers - I would try it.   Otherwise, a replacement brake caliper would be safer.   Assuming you're not bothering to claim warranty from the seller.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the spring or return spring for a side pull or side pull caliper brake. A replacement is usually found by searching for the maker and model of the specific brake.

Finding a replacement will be tough. The complete brake mechanism is very inexpensive making the individual parts so inexpensive they aren't worth keeping in inventory.

Criggie is right, using two pliers or a vice and one plier twist it back into the correct shape and use it.

Springs are supposed to be made of spring steel known for it's ability to be bent and return to it's original shape. In spite of it's ability to bounce back it can be bent in such a way as to hold a new shape.

In your case you need a very small adjustment that should not impact the spring characteristics of the metal.

Comment: Agree that "return spring" is the correct name. For higher-end brakes, I know I've bought and replaced the return springs on Campy Chorus 10s brakes due to cracking, but oddly, my current Shimano brakes don't appear to list the return spring as a spare: https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/BR-R8000/EV-BR-R8000-4251.pdf